# Attach an icon to a folder

Tags: icons, windows-shell

I created a file called "**Desktop.ini**" that has the following lines:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconFile=Icon.ico
IconIndex=0
```

and I have an .ico file with the name "**Icon**"

I put both files in the folder but the folder does not have an attached icon.

When I tried to do the same using the Folder Marker software it works. It creates the same file.

When I do it by myself, it does not. What am I missing here?